# Show Multple Divs based on Multiple Select2 Selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to make a website with no check-boxes and jQuery Select2 seems like the answer. Now, I cannot show multiple divs based on multiple Select2 selections. For example, if OnBase is selected in my dropdown, I want to show the OnBase div, and if OnBase is not selected, hide it.

```
     Script to hide my Divs

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectapps').select2();
    $('#CNKronos').hide();
    $('#Network2').hide();
    $('#Network').hide();
   $('#OnBase').hide();
    });
   </script>

    Script that only shows the div for the first selection only

     <script>

       $(function() {
       $('#ApplicationsList').change(function(){
        $('.selectapps2').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
     });

   </script>

   Select2 Dropdown

   <div id="Applications" class="panel panel-primary" style="width:850px;    margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Applications</strong></h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
               <select class="selectapps selectapps2" id="ApplicationsList"      name="ApplicationsList" multiple="multiple" style="width:99%;">
                <option value="CNKronos" >CNKronos</option>
                <option value="Network2">Drive</option>
                <option value="Network">Email</option>
                <option value="OnBase">OnBase</option>
               </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table> 
        </div>
  </div> 

  DIVS

     <div id="CNKronos" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>CNKronos</strong></h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table> 
        </div>
  </div>      

     <div id="Network2" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Drive</strong></h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table> 
        </div>
  </div>      

     <div id="Network" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Email</strong></h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table> 
        </div>
  </div>      

      <div id="OnBase" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px; ">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>OnBase</strong></h3>
      </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
              <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table> 
        </div>
  </div>      '
```

Can you please help me achieve this? I'm going nuts and couldn't find any other solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for your select2 widget. It actually gives you a means to get at each selected option. Use .select2('data'), and it returns an array of selected objects. Using that, the following code does what you seem to want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Create the select2
  $('.selectapps').select2();
  // hide the sub-panes
  $('.selectapps2').hide();
  
  // When our select2 changes...
  $('#ApplicationsList').change(function(){
    // ... we can get all the selected options
    let selected = $(this).select2('data');
    
    // Hide all the panes again
    $('.selectapps2').hide();
    // Go through the list of options
    selected.forEach( function(option){
      // and show the one with this id
      $("#"+option.id).show()
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div id="Applications" class="panel panel-primary" style="width:850px;    margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Applications</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <select class="selectapps selectapps2" id="ApplicationsList" name="ApplicationsList" multiple="multiple" style="width:99%;">
                <option value="CNKronos" >CNKronos</option>
                <option value="Network2">Drive</option>
                <option value="Network">Email</option>
                <option value="OnBase">OnBase</option>
               </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="CNKronos" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>CNKronos</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Network2" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Drive</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Network" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Email</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="OnBase" class="panel panel-primary selectapps2" style="width:850px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px; ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>OnBase</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table width="825" border="0" class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. I ran this code snippet and it seemed to work but when pasting this into my code, I get syntax error on this line:                                    selected.forEach( (option) => {    Any ideas? I'm so new to jQuery I cannot come up with something.

Comment: It's possible it doesn't like the "fat arrow" function. I've changed the code,  still works the same. Let me know if the update worked.

Comment: Excellent. glad to help. Now... do you understand what it was that i did? ;)

Comment: Yes! you set it to get all selected options by doing select2('data'). Then, we are passing each option selected and showing its div in : selected.forEach( function(option){
$("#"+option.id).show()

Comment: Exactly right. Just wanted this to be a (maybe) teachable moment. Best of luck!

Comment: Now, I just realized that the divs will only show when the form is new, and when it's submitted, I can see my selected options, but the divs are hidden. I guess I have to use other function that will detect "Selected" instead of "Change", do you know how to achieve this? I was thinking that it may be easier to get the values one by one. something like this: if(document.getElementById("ApplicationsList").value == "OnBase"){ Display:block, OnBaseKey== "ON", validate the OnBase section textboxes, etc,etc.} Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a toggle function for each your input selector. Because select2 functionality provides an array as self value, you can iterate over these values and show/hide each div based on it. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectapps').select2();
  $('#CNKronos').hide();
  $('#Network2').hide();
  $('#Network').hide();
  $('#OnBase').hide();
  var idSelectors = ["CNKronos", "Network2", "Network", "OnBase"];

  $('#ApplicationsList').change(function(e) {
    var thisValArray = $(this).val();
    idSelectors.forEach(function(idSelector) {
      $('#' + idSelector).toggle(thisValArray.indexOf(idSelector) === -1);
    });

  });
});
```